# Vim setup with Visual Studio

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2022, vsvim

Its being a while where I am using **VIM** with **VS Code**. But my current project require use of **Visual Studio**. While setting vim for vs code I have modified my **settings.json** and **keybindings.json** files. How do apply that kind of modifications in Visual Studio 2022.

Following are two files from vscode.

***settings.json***

```
{
"vim.easymotion": true,
    "vim.incsearch": true,
    "vim.useSystemClipboard": true,
    "vim.useCtrlKeys": false,
    "vim.hlsearch": true,
    "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
        {
          "before": ["j", "j"],
          "after": ["<Esc>"]
        }
    ],
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
          "before": ["<leader>", "d"],
          "after": ["d", "d"]
        },
        {
          "before": ["<C-n>"],
          "commands": [":nohl"]
        }
    ],
    "vim.leader": "<space>",
    "vim.handleKeys": {
        "<C-a>": false,
        "<C-f>": false
    },
}
```

***keybindings.json***

```
[
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "tab",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorTabMovesFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift-tab",
        "command": "outdent",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorTabMovesFocus"
    }
]
```

**Note:** I have installed VsVim 2022 extension on Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Just a reminder that you are not using Vim at all. Those things are limited Vim emulators, not Vim.

Comment: okay @romainl. But can I configure it in Visual Studio as I did in vs code?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

While in Visual Studio type

```
:set vimrcpaths?
```

This will show you directory where the plugin looks for the .vimsrc file.
Place the config file there and restart Visual Studio.

I assume you have the VsVim extension installed (it's different than the one for VS Code).